# Holding random effects variance constant in PROC MIXED vs lmer

Tags: sas, lme4, mixed-models

**I was wondering if it is possible to hold random effects variances constant in `R's` `lme` or `lmer` functions** (or another random effects routine in `R`) or at least to provide starting values.

This appears to be possible in SAS using the *parms* statement in `PROC MIXED`.  In a paper by [Selya et al. (2012)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3328081/) the authors use this to set the variance parameters for a model with a simpler fixed effects structure to those of a full model.

The specific call within PROC MIXED they use is `parms/parmsdata = fullmodel.AB hold = ...`  Their goal is to hold variance estimates constant across models with different fixed effects structures (though I wonder if this is truly possible in either SAS or R).

Comment: Since (in a flag) you characterize this as a *coding* question and ask that it be migrated to [SO], I will do so.  It is possible that you might not be able to get the desired result directly from any existing `R` package, in which case some theoretical analysis would be needed to show how to do the calculation in the first place, which would bring you right back here to the stats site... .

Answer (score 1):

Try `gnlrim` on github.  It can do maximum likelihood with bounds on the parameters.  Just set the starting value, lower bound and upper bound to the same value for the random intercept variance `pmix` and it will be held constant.

Below is an example that shows `gnlrim` estimates the same model as `lmer` with `REML=FALSE`.  The first chunks are for easy copy and paste; the subsequent chunks show the execution of pertinent lines.

Setup packages, data, and fit models (copy and paste chunk):

```
library(devtools)
## if you have macOS, grab this version of libstableR:
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr / libstableR")
devtools::install_github(  "swihart/gnlrim")

## data: 4 individuals with 5 observations
dose <- c(9,12,4,9,11,10,2,11,12,9,9,9,4,9,11,9,14,7,9,8)
y <- c(8.674419, 11.506066, 11.386742, 27.414532, 12.135699,  4.359469,
       1.900681, 17.425948,  4.503345,  2.691792,  5.731100, 10.534971,
       11.220260,  6.968932,  4.094357, 16.393806, 14.656584,  8.786133,
       20.972267, 17.178012)
id <- rep(1:4, each=5)

## fit with lmer
lmer_fit <- lme4::lmer(y~dose + (1|id), REML=FALSE)

## fit with gnlrim
gnlrim_fit <-
gnlrim(y,
       mu=~a+b*dose+rand,
       random="rand",
       nest=id,
       pmu=c(a=8.7,b=0.25),
       pshape = c(shape=1),
       pmix=c(var=3.0938^2),
       p_uppb = c(10,  1, 5, 3.0938^3),
       p_lowb = c( 5, -1, 0, 0)
       )
```

Run these lines to see how similar the models are (copy and paste chunk):

```
## show fits are the same:

## intercept (a) slope (b)
summary(lmer_fit)$coeff[,1]
gnlrim_fit$coeff[1:2]

## Residuals standard deviation
## sigma_epsilon = 5.58
summary(lmer_fit)$varcor
sqrt(exp(gnlrim_fit$coeff[3]))

## random effects standard deviation
## sigma_id = 3.0938
summary(lmer_fit)$varcor
sqrt(gnlrim_fit$coeff[4])

## likelihood
summary(lmer_fit)$logLik
-gnlrim_fit$maxlike
```

Take the same model, but run it setting and holding the random effects variance constant (copy and paste chunk):

```
## Take same model but hold constant
## random effects standard deviation
## sigma_id   :=  9
## sigma^2_id := 81
gnlrim_fit2 <-
  gnlrim(y,
         mu=~a+b*dose+rand,
         random="rand",
         nest=id,
         pmu=c(a=8.7,b=0.25),
         pshape = c(shape=1),
         pmix=c(var=9^2),
         p_uppb = c(10,  1, 5, 9^2),
         p_lowb = c( 5, -1, 0, 9^2)
  )

gnlrim_fit2$coeff
gnlrim_fit2$se
```

### Execution of lines showing models are similar:

```
> ## show fits are the same:
> ## intercept (a) slope (b)
> summary(lmer_fit)$coeff[,1]
(Intercept)        dose 
  8.7117914   0.2488724 
> gnlrim_fit$coeff[1:2]
[1] 8.7118426 0.2488648
> 
> ## Residuals standard deviation
> ## sigma_epsilon = 5.58
> summary(lmer_fit)$varcor
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 3.0938  
 Residual             5.5880  
> sqrt(exp(gnlrim_fit$coeff[3]))
[1] 5.587926
> 
> ## random effects standard deviation
> ## sigma_id = 3.0938
> summary(lmer_fit)$varcor
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 3.0938  
 Residual             5.5880  
> sqrt(gnlrim_fit$coeff[4])
[1] 3.094191
> 
> ## likelihood
> summary(lmer_fit)$logLik
'log Lik.' -64.64964 (df=4)
> -gnlrim_fit$maxlike
[1] -64.64958
```

### Execution of lines for holding constant variance:

```
> ## Take same model but hold constant
> ## random effects standard deviation
> ## sigma_id   :=  9
> ## sigma^2_id := 81
> gnlrim_fit2 <-
+   gnlrim(y,
+          mu=~a+b*dose+rand,
+          random="rand",
+          nest=id,
+          pmu=c(a=8.7,b=0.25),
+          pshape = c(shape=1),
+          pmix=c(var=9^2),
+          p_uppb = c(10,  1, 5, 9^2),
+          p_lowb = c( 5, -1, 0, 9^2)
+   )
> 
> gnlrim_fit2$coeff
[1]  9.1349920  0.2012785  3.4258404 81.0000000
> gnlrim_fit2$se
[1] 6.1006729 0.4420228 0.3485940 0.0000000
```