# linear mixed model with fix var component in R

Tags: fixed, lme4, variance, varcomp

It is straightforward to build an LMM with fixed variance components in SAS.
For example, variance components = 5 and 10 (experimental error and sampling error, respectively)

```
proc glimmix; class trt rep;
model y = trt;
random rep(trt);
parms (5)(10) / hold=1,2;
ods output tests3=power_terms;
```

But it looks like R has no option to fix the variance components.

I can not find the solution in the manual of Lmer.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588873/holding-random-effects-variance-constant-in-proc-mixed-vs-lmer/47107612#47107612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done slightly more easily in `glmmTMB`:

```r
data("sleepstudy", package = "lme4")
library(glmmTMB)
m1 <- glmmTMB(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject),
        family = gaussian,
        data = sleepstudy,
        start = list(betad = log(5),
                   theta = log(10)/2),
        map = list(betad = factor(NA), theta = factor(NA))
)
```

Running `Anova`:

```r
car::Anova(m1, type = "3")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Reaction
            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept) 97012  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
Days        32541  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note that finite-size corrections (i.e. F instead of chi-square tests) are not implemented for glmmTMB objects ...

*Explanation*:

- the `map` argument specifies which model parameters to hold fixed or equal to each other: `NA` specifies "hold fixed". `betad` is the set of parameters controlling dispersion/residual variance, `theta` controls the random effects variance
- the `start` argument gives the starting values, which are the fixed values that will be applied when `map` is in effect. Residual variance is specified on the log-variance scale; random-effects variance is specified on the log-standard-deviation scale.

Excerpt from output:

```
Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 3.162   
 Residual             2.236
```

These values are `sqrt(10)` and `sqrt(5)`, respectively.

You can also do this by specifying very narrow priors in the `blme` package. In `lme4` random effect variances can be fixed by writing a wrapper function for the negative log-likelihood function and doing the optimization yourself (see `?lme4::modular`), but residual variances can't be fixed because they are profiled out of the log-likelihood expression.

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving this. It works well 
 <`a <- data.frame(trt=c(1,2), y=c(95,100))
b <- expand.grid(samples=c(1,2),rep=1:4)
data <- merge(a, b)

library(glmmTMB)
fit <- glmmTMB(y ~ trt + (1|trt:rep), data = data, family = gaussian(),start = list(betad = log(5),
                   theta = log(10)/2),
        map = list(betad = factor(NA), theta = factor(NA)))
summary(fit)`> . One problem is the glmmTMB does not support downstream F test, when I try to extract the F value for the model with the code 'anv <-  Anova(fit, type = 3)' Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Someone did start to implement Satterthwaite df computations for glmmTMB objects, but I'm not sure where we left off ...